# create a employee in biometric machine using odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8, biometrics

i am trying to many time create user using odoo 8 custom button using this code please help me.

```
@api.multi
def createBioUsers(self):
    zk = zklib.ZKLib(config.key['ip'], int(config.key['port']))
    res = zk.connect()
    if res == False:
        zk.enableDevice()
        zk.disableDevice()
        zk.setUser(uid=8888, userid=8888, name='Ehtisham Faisal', 
        password='1234', role=zkconst.LEVEL_USER)
        zk.enableDevice()
        zk.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWVS3ojgcAo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCL15yJBNuI&feature=youtu.be
https://github.com/saasier1/saasier_public_addons/tree/master/fingerprint_scanner
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/is-there-a-fingerprint-scanner-that-feeds-into-hr-attendance-66704

I hope this information will help